# Nestjs: Module '"@nestjs/jwt"' has no exported member 'JwtModule'.ts(2305)

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

Im doing the freecodecamp course NestJS, and Im trying to implement nestjs/jwt.

1. Installed the dependencies: `npm install @nestjs/passport passport @nestjs/jwt passport-jwt`
2. Trying to import the module in my auth.module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { PrismaModule } from 'src/prisma/prisma.module';

//Authentication
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'; //here
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Module({
    imports: [PrismaModule, JwtModule.register()],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

But im getting this error: Module '"@nestjs/jwt"' has no exported member 'JwtModule'.ts(2305)

Comment: And you're certain that `@nestjs/jwt` is what was installed, and not something like `nestjs/jwt`? Can you verify in your `package.json`?

Comment: This is the npm command: `npm install @nestjs/passport passport @nestjs/jwt passport-jwt`

Comment: "@nestjs/jwt": "github:nestjs/jwt",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong with the install, as it's pointing at github rather than at npm. The GitHub code is in Typescript and doesn't match what the package.json says it should be exporting, so the error is correct. Change `github:nestjs/jwt` to `^10.0.0` and re-install and everything should work

Comment: 1. changend the  json to ^10.0.0
2. Delete node modules
3. npm install

Result: Same error. error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/jwt"' has no exported member 'JwtModule'.

Comment: I updated my question so i add it the dependencies and devDependencies.

Comment: I repetead the previous proce twice and it work, thanks.